# How to use ruby on rails to achieve multiple layers of each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**The prototype is as follows**

```
a = [[2,3],[7,8,9],[4.12]]
```

**I need to**

```
[2,3].each do |i_1|
    [7,8,9].each do |i_2|
        a = i_1 * i_2
        [4, 12].each do |i_3|
            b = a * i_3
            p b
        end
    end
end
```

**But if many combinations are in the Array**

```
a = [[2,3],[7,8,9],[4.12],.......]
```

How to do ?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using [each_with_index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) directly on your array `a = [[2,3],[7,8,9],[4.12]]` will help you achieve what you want.